# Google Spread Sheets API Problems

Tags: google-sheets-api

I have spend a long time looking for an answer but nothing works. I need to edit a cell in a spreadsheet.

const TicketASheet = doc.sheetsByTitle['Ticket-A'];

```
            let RowtoFind = ticketid - 1;

            if(tickettype == "A"){
                SheetToUse = TicketASheet

                await SheetToUse.loadCells('A1:AAA1000');
                status = SheetToUse.getCell(RowtoFind, 1).value
                creator = SheetToUse.getCell(RowtoFind, 2).value
                claiment = SheetToUse.getCell(RowtoFind, 3).value
                department = SheetToUse.getCell(RowtoFind, 4).value
                datemade = SheetToUse.getCell(RowtoFind, 5).value
                timemade = SheetToUse.getCell(RowtoFind, 6).value
                Subject = SheetToUse.getCell(RowtoFind, 7).value
                Content = SheetToUse.getCell(RowtoFind, 8).value
                Notes = SheetToUse.getCell(RowtoFind, 9).value

            }
```

Later Down (Not Working)
`SheetToUse.getRange("c2").setValue("AAA");`

I have multiple sheets that can change. (The reason why it's SheetToUse). It's all in a async function.

I also don't think that .setvalue is a function, my main question is how to change the value of a cell.

Comment: How you define `SheetToUse`? Could you include more snippet of your code?

Comment: Hello,
`const TicketASheet = doc.sheetsByTitle['Ticket-A'];`
`SheetToUse = TicketASheet`
`await SheetToUse.loadCells('A1:AAA1000');`
`status = SheetToUse.getCell(RowtoFind, 1).value`

All of this code works. The part below does not.
`SheetToUse.getRange("c2").setValue("AAA");`

Comment: What framework and package are you using? I tried checking the `npm` and look for a package that has getRange() and setValue() and found nothing. Given that the method can't be found anywhere in the `npm` and the usage of the code, I believe you are using the Spreadsheet Service for Google Apps Script. References: [getRange](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange(String)), [setValue](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluevalue)

Comment: I'm using the google-spreadsheet node module. I have found tutorials online for .setValue but none of them work for me.

Comment: Could you link which node module are you using? Upon checking the documentation of [google-spreadsheet](https://theoephraim.github.io/node-google-spreadsheet/#/) there are no getRange and setValue methods in the module.

Comment: Although you say there are none of those methods, I have seen tutorials with them unless it has changed. The main question I have now Is how do I change cells. Is this what you mean? https://theoephraim.github.io/node-google-spreadsheet/#/

Comment: You can follow this sample code from the document on how to change cell value : [Working with cells](https://theoephraim.github.io/node-google-spreadsheet/#/?id=working-with-cells)

Comment: That ended up working! Thanks so much!